# How to rotate the UIActivityViewController on iOS14?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

We are trying to rotate the UIActivityViewController in an only portrait app. Since the app is in portrait, we have mimicked UI Rotation, but we are having troubles with rotating the actual UIActivityViewController. [[image: Normal Result] How it looks normally [image: Actual Result] How it looks rotated

Using the setRotation function on the activity controller itself causes the view to rotate weirdly as it is a child of a bigger frame. Is there a better way to rotate the view or should the view be rotated at all?

This is the current code that deals with the rotation

```
let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
        
activityController.view.setRotation(angle: 90);
        
activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = newView;
activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect( x: 0, y: 200, width: 768, height: 20);
```